# Why does the picture appear over the top-fixed menu?

Tags: html, css

I've set a top menu using the following CSS:

```
 position:fixed; top:0;
```

When I scroll down the page, it works properly. However, when there's a picture, the pictures block the appearance of the menu, as shown below:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Any suggestions?

Comment: `top: [height of the menu]px` or z-index

Comment: Suggestion: Share your code, not images. We can't guess things here.

Comment: brewal, your code didn't work, it just set the menu in another place..anyway thanks for trying to help.@Cyril Beeckman's code worked succesfully! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
z-index: 2;
```

On your topbar.

** Updated **

Comment: whoahh yeah, that's what i wanted :D THANK YOU!

Comment: Please +1 useful answer and close your question.

Comment: i marked your answer, but how to close the question?

Comment: That's all thank you.